# ejabberd extauth via python+mysql issues

Tags: python, mysql, ejabberd

im trying to implement external authorisation in

### ejabberd.x86_64                        18.06-0

via python+mysql https://github.com/rankenstein/ejabberd-auth-mysql and got error bellow, please help me to figure out what i've miss. Without mysql, authorisation via python script works fine, but in my case something goes wrong and i'm currently stuck.

### Client psi+

```
2018-09-13 08:20:18.911 [info] <0.348.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:272 (<0.485.0>) Accepted connection ::ffff:x.x.x.x:59827 -> ::ffff:x.x.x.x:5222
2018-09-13 08:20:18.911 [debug] <0.485.0>@xmpp_socket:parse:374 (tcp|<0.485.0>) Received XML on stream = <<"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<stream:stream xmlns:stream=\"http://etherx.jabber.org/streams\" version=\"1.0\" xmlns=\"jabber:client\" to=\"chatstageejabberd.example.com\" xml:lang=\"ru\" xmlns:xml=\"http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace\">\n">>
2018-09-13 08:20:18.912 [debug] <0.485.0>@xmpp_socket:send:224 (tcp|<0.485.0>) Send XML on stream = <<"<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream id='7822881988001039051' version='1.0' xml:lang='ru' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' from='chatstageejabberd.example.com' xmlns='jabber:client'>">>
2018-09-13 08:20:18.912 [debug] <0.485.0>@xmpp_socket:send:224 (tcp|<0.485.0>) Send XML on stream = <<"<stream:features><starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'><required/></starttls></stream:features>">>
2018-09-13 08:20:18.953 [debug] <0.485.0>@xmpp_socket:parse:374 (tcp|<0.485.0>) Received XML on stream = <<"<starttls xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls\"/>">>
2018-09-13 08:20:18.953 [debug] <0.485.0>@shaper:update:144 MaxRate=1000, BurstSize=1000, AcquiredCredit=1000, Size=51, NewAcquiredCredit=990, Pause=0
2018-09-13 08:20:18.954 [debug] <0.485.0>@xmpp_socket:send:224 (tcp|<0.485.0>) Send XML on stream = <<"<proceed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>">>
2018-09-13 08:20:19.099 [debug] <0.485.0>@xmpp_socket:parse:374 (tls|<0.485.0>) Received XML on stream = <<"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<stream:stream xmlns:stream=\"http://etherx.jabber.org/streams\" version=\"1.0\" xmlns=\"jabber:client\" to=\"chatstageejabberd.example.com\" xml:lang=\"ru\" xmlns:xml=\"http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace\">\n">>
2018-09-13 08:20:19.099 [debug] <0.485.0>@shaper:update:144 MaxRate=1000, BurstSize=1000, AcquiredCredit=990, Size=225, NewAcquiredCredit=910, Pause=0
2018-09-13 08:20:19.099 [debug] <0.485.0>@xmpp_socket:send:224 (tls|<0.485.0>) Send XML on stream = <<"<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream id='13987711731833743230' version='1.0' xml:lang='ru' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' from='chatstageejabberd.example.com' xmlns='jabber:client'>">>
2018-09-13 08:20:19.099 [debug] <0.485.0>@xmpp_socket:send:224 (tls|<0.485.0>) Send XML on stream = <<"<stream:features><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms><register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/><auth xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth'/></stream:features>">>
2018-09-13 08:20:19.142 [debug] <0.485.0>@xmpp_socket:parse:374 (tls|<0.485.0>) Received XML on stream = <<"<auth xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl\" mechanism=\"PLAIN\">AG15dXNlcgB2bW1mY0h5SDB1bTA=</auth>">>
2018-09-13 08:20:19.142 [debug] <0.485.0>@shaper:update:144 MaxRate=1000, BurstSize=1000, AcquiredCredit=1000, Size=100, NewAcquiredCredit=942, Pause=0
2018-09-13 08:20:19.144 [debug] <0.467.0>@extauth:handle_call:119 Received response from external authentication program: [0,0]
2018-09-13 08:20:19.144 [info] <0.485.0>@ejabberd_c2s:handle_auth_failure:443 (tls|<0.485.0>) Failed c2s PLAIN authentication for myuser@chatstageejabberd.example.com from ::ffff:x.x.x.x: Invalid username or password
2018-09-13 08:20:19.144 [debug] <0.485.0>@xmpp_socket:send:224 (tls|<0.485.0>) Send XML on stream = <<"<failure xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><not-authorized/><text xml:lang='en'>Invalid username or password</text></failure>">>
2018-09-13 08:20:19.187 [debug] <0.485.0>@xmpp_socket:send:224 (tls|<0.485.0>) Send XML on stream = <<"</stream:stream>">>
```

ejabberd.yml

```
loglevel: 5
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rotate_count: 1
log_rate_limit: 100
hosts:
  - "chatstageejabberd.example.com"
certfiles:
  - "/opt/ejabberd/conf/server.pem"
ca_file: "/opt/ejabberd/conf/cacert.pem"
listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    starttls: true
    starttls_required: true
    max_stanza_size: 65536
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    certfile: "/opt/ejabberd/conf/server.pem"
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 131072
    shaper: s2s_shaper
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
      "/api": mod_http_api
    web_admin: true
    register: true
    captcha: false
  -
    port: 5281
    ip: "127.0.0.1"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/api": mod_http_api
disable_sasl_mechanisms: 
  - "digest-md5"
  - "X-OAUTH2"
  - "SCRAM-SHA-1"
s2s_use_starttls: required
auth_password_format: plain
fqdn: "chatstageejabberd.example.com"
auth_method: external
extauth_program: "python /opt/ejabberd/auth.py"
extauth_pool_size: 3
auth_use_cache: false
shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000
max_fsm_queue: 10000
acl:
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin1@chatstageejabberd.example.com"
      - "test4@chatstageejabberd.example.com"
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - "127.0.0.0/8"
      - "::1/128"
      - "::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128"
shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    - 5000: admin
    - 100
  c2s_shaper:
    - none: admin
    - normal
  s2s_shaper: fast
access_rules:
  local:
    - allow: local
  c2s:
    - deny: blocked
    - allow
  announce:
    - allow: admin
  configure:
    - allow: admin
  muc_create:
    - allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    - allow: local
  register:
    - allow
  trusted_network:
    - allow: loopback
api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      - access:
          - allow:
            - acl: loopback
            - acl: admin
      - oauth:
        - scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        - access:
          - allow:
            - acl: loopback
            - acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      - ip: "127.0.0.1/8"
    what:
      - "status"
      - "connected_users_number"
      - "register"
      - "*"
language: "en"
acme:
   contact: "mailto:admin@chatstageejabberd"
   ca_url: "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org"
modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce: # recommends mod_adhoc
    access: announce
  mod_blocking: {} # requires mod_privacy
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {} # requires mod_adhoc
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_last: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    default_room_options:
      allow_subscription: true
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    ignore_pep_from_offline: true
    last_item_cache: false
    max_items_node: 10
    plugins:
      - "flat"
      - "pep" # pep requires mod_caps
    force_node_config:
      "eu.siacs.conversations.axolotl.*":
        access_model: whitelist
      "storage:bookmarks":
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    welcome_message:
      subject: "Welcome!"
      body: |-
        Hi.
        Welcome to this XMPP server.
    ip_access: trusted_network
    access: register
  mod_roster: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_vcard:
    search: false
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_version: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt: {}
  mod_legacy_auth: {}
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
allow_contrib_modules: true
```

Comment: I've found the solution by myself, should be used correct placeholder in sql line.